# Image Analysis of Flames trying to Detect Edge for Curve Fit not always working MatLab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, curve-fitting, edge-detection

I am trying to figure out how to make a program in Matlab to detect edges of flames so I can compare their flame shape.  I have been able to get this program to work half of the time. The program reads the files, coverts it to black and white, and then I have been having issues with the `bwboundaries` function (I think).

It will work some times and not others depending on the picture, they can be seen below.

Any help anyone could give me would be appreciated. I am struggling here to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
clear, clc , close all
%% Specify the folder where the files live.
%myFolder = 'D:\Try';
myFolder = 'D:\Try\PicNamed\SpTestTry\hope';

%% Check to make sure that folder actually exists.  
if ~isdir(myFolder)
    errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does not exist:\n%s', myFolder);
    uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
    return;
end
%% Get a list of all files in the folder with the pattern
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.jpg'); % Change to whatever need.
theFiles = dir(filePattern);

line = cell(length(theFiles), 1) ;
rValue = cell(length(theFiles),1);

baseFileName = theFiles(1).name;
fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);  
imageArray = imread(fullFileName); 

% getting the rectanglur cords to crop the images
[I2, rect] = imcrop(imageArray);

%% Run Loop
for k = 1 : length(theFiles)

    %Pulling in multiple Images from folder 
    baseFileName = theFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);  
    imageArray = imread(fullFileName); 


    %%  Cropping Image with Rect Cords
    Icrop = imcrop(imageArray,rect);  

    %%  convert to bw
    BW = im2bw(Icrop, graythresh(Icrop));

    %%   Get Boundries 
    boundaries = bwboundaries(BW);
    % putting in x and y cord
    x = boundaries{1}(:, 2);
    y = boundaries{1}(:, 1);  

    %%  Curve Fit
    %pulling up picture of x,y plot to determing where base of flame is
    figure
    plot(x, y)

    % cutting off bottom of flame edge so we can do curve fit
    prompt = '(******) cut off line = ';
    cutnum = input(prompt);

    indices = find(abs(y)>cutnum);
    y(indices) = NaN;
    y(indices) = [];
    x(indices) = [];

    %% Looking for repate x values, averaging them together, and replacing with 1 x value

    uc1 = unique( x ) ;
    mc2 = accumarray( x, y, [], @mean ) ;
    newData = [uc1, mc2(uc1)];

    %% splitting AA into two sperate matricies, i.e. x/y cordinates
    y = newData(:,2);
    x = newData(:,1);

    %% Creating a line Based off of the averaged x and y cords
    [p,S] = polyfit(x,y,4); % 4th degree polynomail
    line{k} = p;
    rValue{k} = S.normr;
    Rsquared{k}=1-S.normr^2/norm(y-mean(y))^2;

    close all

    clear BW
    clear x
    clear y
end
```

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

Comment: if you dont provide the data, no one can hepl

Comment: Since I am a new user I can't  have more than two links uploaded until I get more rep.  I have combined the two graphs and linked a smaller size pic.  Sorry for the issues. Hopefully this will suffice for now.  I will try to find a way to upload all the originals ones.

Comment: Now that I have edited it, does te system allow you to add more? Can you add an image from when it goes bad an an image for when it goes good?

Comment: I dont know how to add more images to this account since I just made it today (they wont allow me to post with more than to pics/link to pics)

Comment: The graph pictures are when they are good and bad.  Good on the right, bad on the left.   the right picture has a nice "parabola" flame shape where the left is drawing a line from data points that are going all over the place. Different pics of flames under similar settings, using the same code, but getting different graphed lines.

Comment: I went ahead and combined the original, the cropped, the binary, and the line it graphed from bwboundaries.  I got the x and y for the graph using this part of the code:          
            boundaries = bwboundaries(BW);     
            % putting in x and y cord;       
             x = boundaries{1}(:, 2);     
             y = boundaries{1}(:, 1);